# Migrating from Electric to Fuerte

Tags: ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to migrate from Electric to Fuerte. Is it a good practise to keep the previous electric stacks? In my opinion if Fuerte provides backward compatibility, then i can just ignore electric. Or, if I install fuerte then, ros will manage by itself(assuming I'm too optimist in this case).

Any good link to assist this migration(related commands etc)

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47919/migrating-from-electric-to-fuerte/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-11-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is the main [Fuerte migration page](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Migration).

In your tags you mention Ubuntu 12.04, Precise. Electric is not supported on that distribution. If you need both, use Ubuntu 10.10, Oneiric, instead.

ROS distributions are packaged so they can coexist on a single system. I find it helpful to keep both the old and new version when upgrading.

- Make sure each shell only sources the setup for a single version.
- Always cleanly recompile all source overlays for the target version. I find it simplest to check out separate copies.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-11-10**:
@joq: Thanks a lot . That helps a lot.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-11-10**:
@joq: Could you point me to any thread/discussion mentioning about installing from "source vs  prebuilt". I know the existance of this link "http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu" but there are people saying that it's better to install the one that requiring building from source.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-11-10**:
What say you?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-11-10**:
I can't think of any advantage to building from source. That seems to be significantly more difficult with Fuerte.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-11-10**:
Great answer. Thanks.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-11-10**:
@joq ...... another chapter of joqian wisdom ! :-) ...... all in good spirit ! :-)

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-11-10**:
Indeed! couldn't agree more.